# Social_stream gem migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, social-stream

I have been trying to install the social_stream engine in rails 4.2.3. I'm following the guide from their home page [(http://social-stream.dit.upm.es/started/#rails)][1] Everything works until I try to migrate.

I get the following error

```
undefined method `database_authenticatable' for #`<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition`
```

I have tried installing this as a Mountable Engines as shown in a rails cast. That also doesn't work.

this is how my gem file looks

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'social_stream'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

I'm using cloud ide. cloud9.io. Please help me resolve this issue as I really want to try this engine out. Please let me know if there are any resources on how to install and get it working. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you generated installation as follows: `rails generate social_stream:install`?

Comment: yes. that created all the migration files. Then I have to migrate the database in order to be able to run the app. so when I do rake db:migrate the migration error shows up

Comment: Show full trace stack please